# Repeatedly iterating through a list, with buttons and bindings

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tkinter, iteration

So I'm making a maths test in TkInter (Python 3.4.3). I want to use only one frame for all questions. I have a list that contains all of the strings (`QStringList`, imported from another .py), which are used as the text variables for a label.

When the user presses <kbd>Return</kbd>, or the Button, I want to iterate to the next item in the list, so there's a new question displayed.
With my current code, I can only successfully do this once. Presumably because the 'CurrentQ' variable gets set back to 0 each time.
How do do this so that each time I call the function, the next list item is displayed?

This code is in my `TestPage(tk.Frame):` class.

```
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

    CurrentQ = 0

    #QUESTION LABEL
    self.CurrentQStringVar = tk.StringVar()
    self.CurrentQString = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.CurrentQStringVar,
                               anchor='w',fg="black", bg="yellow", font=STANDARD_FONT)
    self.CurrentQString.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2, sticky='EW')
    self.CurrentQStringVar.set(QStringList[CurrentQ])

    #ANSWER ENTRY BOX
    self.UserAnsEntryVar = tk.StringVar()
    self.UserAnsEntry = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=self.UserAnsEntryVar)
    self.UserAnsEntry.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='EW')
    self.UserAnsEntry.bind("<Return>",
                           lambda event, CurrentQ=CurrentQ:
                           self.TestEnterKey(self,CurrentQ))
    self.UserAnsEntryVar.set("")

    #ANSWER BUTTON
    self.UserAnsButtonVar = tk.StringVar()
    self.UserAnsButton = ttk.Button(self,text="ENTER",
                                    command= lambda: self.TestEnterKey(self,CurrentQ))
    self.UserAnsButton.grid(column=0,row=2,columnspan=2, stick='EW')

def TestEnterKey(self,event,CurrentQ):
    CurrentQ += 1
    self.CurrentQStringVar.set(QStringList[CurrentQ])
    return CurrentQ
```

I tried to use the `CurrentQ` as an argument in the function, but maybe I have to use a `lambda`.

edit: my actual QStringList is really long, and contains other (randomly generated) variables. So for this I guess it'd be better to just have...

```
QStringList = ["Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8","Q9","Q10"]
```

Comment: @Please add the question list to your code to make if fully working.

Comment: ah yeah, sorry, I've added it to the bottom, thanks

Comment: Please provide your full code since there some things missing (class definition, generating class instance, mainloop(), ...). Due to that, your code is not runnable. Please provide a minimal, working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use `lambda`. Lambda has its uses, but you rarely need it in Tkinter programs, and as often as not it just makes the code more complicated without giving anything in return.

Instead, make the function that is called from the binding and from the button fetch the data it needs, when it needs it. Since the binding sends an event and the command button does not, simply make the event parameter optional.

Also, make `CurrentQ` an attribute of the object so that it's easily accessible and doesn't have to be passed around.

```
def __init__(self,parent,controller):
    ...
    self.CurrentQ = 0
    ...
    self.UserAnsEntry.bind("<Return>",self.TestEnterKey)
    ...
    self.UserAnsButton = ttk.Button(self,text="ENTER", command=self.TestEnterKey)
    ...

def TestEnterKey(self,event=None):
    self.CurrentQ += 1
    self.CurrentQStringVar.set(QStringList[self.CurrentQ])
```

Another way you could cycle through the list of questions is to always use the first item in the list, and then move the first item to the end. Python has a function that does something similar, letting you cycle through a list indefinitely. See [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

For example:

```
import itertools
...
self.questions = itertools.cycle(self.QStringList)
...
# this will always return the next question, looping
# back over the list as needed
next_question = self.questions.next()
```

Finally, you might want to consider *not* using a `StringVar` with the label. There's really no need unless you're using the `StringVar` in more than one place. Without it you can still change the text in the label, but you have one less object in your project that you have to manage.

For example:

```
question = self.questions.next()
self.CurrentQString.configure(text=question)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works a charm! I'm glad I came here, I would never have thought of that. You've probably saved me hours (which is good because school starts again on Monday, should be finished by then).